# Why doesn't the soil get depleted after repeated clearing of vegetation?

Tags: botany, nutrition, agriculture, soil, vegetation

In my neighborhood, there is a hillside owned and maintained by the local municipality.  The hillside is generally overgrown with vegetation.  Work crews clear out the vegetation multiple times throughout the spring and summer, yet it always grows back quickly.

The workers don't leave the cuttings there.  They haul them away.  So that means the soil of the hillside is losing nutrients.  **Yet why does the vegetation always grow back?**

Hypotheses:

1. It all looks like weeds to me, but maybe there is a natural cycle of crop rotation going on that I can't appreciate.  I.e., in year 1 it was all Type A weeds, then in year 2 it was all Type B weeds, then in year 3 it was all Type C weeds, and then in year 4 it was back to Type A weeds again.
2. Maybe some other natural process is bringing nutrients back to the soil of the hillside.  Bird droppings?  Earthworms?  Insects?  Underground fungus and bacterial colonies?  Small mammal feces?  (I don't think rain runoff is bringing many nutrients because there is nothing but a highway above the hillside.)
3. Maybe the hillside *is* getting depleted and will eventually become barren, it just takes a while.  I guess you have to keep clearing, year after year, until it gets down to the very last and most hardy of the weeds before it becomes truly barren and lifeless.

Comment: Yes (kind of) to all your hypotheses. You'd benefit, for starters, by reading about succession, pioneer species, plant strategies, nitrogen fixation + plant symbioses (e.g., refer to legumes), and nitrogen content of animal waste

Comment: @theforestecologist — If you post your comment as an answer, I'll give you the checkmark.